# Keystone v5 with graphql

Tags: graphql, keystonejs

I started building backend with keystone v5 and graphql, i have to make an api of signup and login and don't know how to proceed with it, also i want to know the folder structure

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Authentication Guide](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/authentication)? The next step after that will be to add [Access Control](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/access-control)?

If you're just getting started you might also want to take a look at the [getting started guide](https://www.keystonejs.com/quick-start/).

There's no real folder structure you need to follow. A minimal API with signup and login could be a single index file.

If you want to build a front-end app to talk to the API you can use anything you like. Keystone is headless.